# Flutter Dynamic list in Carousel Slider item

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, dynamic, carousel-slider

I have a dynamic list image from the server and I want to push them in Carousel Slider.
but when I've added them in the item, and run, I've got this error :

```
Class 'String' has no instance method 'map'.
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Builder)
```

and this is my code.

```
 child: Container(
        // width: pageWidth * 0.84,
        height: pageWidth * 0.42,
        child: CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: pageWidth * 0.42,
              aspectRatio: 1,
              viewportFraction: 1,
              autoPlay: true,
              autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds:5),
              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,


        ),

           items : [
       ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context ,index){
      return  homeView.details![index]['Image'];})].map((i){
        return Builder(
          builder:(BuildContext context) {
            return    ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: homeView.details!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    width: pageWidth * 0.84,
                    height: pageWidth * 0.42,
                    // margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        image: NetworkImage(i),
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(15),),));});});}).toList(),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CarouselSlider.builder()`

`CarouselSlider.builder( itemCount: 15, itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex, int pageViewIndex) => Container( child: Text(itemIndex.toString()), ), )`